# Python lists and new lists

Tags: python-2.7

I am a complete newbie to programming and I am learning Python. I am writing the following:

```
list = ["de", "sandy", "ger"]
```

I want the elements that are less than 4 words to go into a new list called `newList`. Any help please. I have done this so far:

```
list= ["de", "sandy", "ger"]

newlist =[]

for name in list:
    if len(name) <4:
        print name

newlist.append(name[0:3]) 

print newlist
```

This only produced one of the elements for me.

Comment: Maybe you have some problem with your identation, try using the stack overflow editor to paste your exact code. Python is identation sensitive so your `append` should be aligned with the `print name`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing a thing doesn't make it appended to anywhere else.

```
list = ["de", "sandy", "ger"]

newlist = []

for name in list:
    if len(name) < 4:
        newlist.append(name)

print newlist
```

Do **not** do this:

```
newlist.append(name[0:3])
```

This is using the last result from the `for` loop, which leads to unwanted behavior. This means "take the first 3 characters from the last processed value of the for loop, and append it to the empty newlist".

Comment: Thank you so much for that  I've just started 3 weeks so I'm really trying to understand thanks again